# Unity C# code to make my AI move not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am in the process of creating a 3D single-player FPS and am currently working on the movement of the enemies in the game. As this is my first game and doesn't know C# that much I followed a tutorial to do this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z1t7MNk0c4

the tutorial was for 2d but said that it would wor for 3d as well
here is the script that I have

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class movment_shoot : MonoBehaviour {

     public float speed;
     public float stoppingDistance;
     public float retreatDistance;

     private Transform player;

     void Start() {
         player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

     }

     void Update() {

         if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stoppingDistance) {

             transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * 
 Time.deltaTime);

         } else if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < stoppingDistance && 
 Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > retreatDistance) {

            transform.position = this.transform.position;

         } else if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < retreatDistance){

             transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, -speed * 
 Time.deltaTime);
         }


     }
 }`
```

I have not added the shooting part yet when I run the game the enemy I have applied the script to teleports to a location just outside the terrain whilst the game is still playing if you move the enemy along if you try and move it along the x or z axes it will only move along x then go back to the original position if you move it along the y it will let you but then move back to its original position please help with anyways I can make this work correctly.

Comment: If your game is 3d, you would need to change the vector2's to vector3...

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention with vectors in unity: lower dimensionality vectors operations "cut out" excess dimensions.

Your problem is that the Z is completely left out of the equation .

You just need to use the methods of the Vector3 class rather than Vector2.